# Python Pyautogui: Why doesn't he right click in my code?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have made a script that checks 100 times whether an image can be detected. He clicks it if it is seen in the last if statement. But a few things are going wrong here.

1: He doesn't right-click what I do.

2: after clicking my script closes immediately!

What did I do wrong? and how do I fix this?

This is my code

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time
import subprocess

def openprogram():
    #opens program
    subprocess.call(["cmd", "/c", "start", "/max", "D:\FarmHelper3.exe"])    

def inloggen():
    #searches for image 100 times to login
    for _ in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        coords = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/login.png')
        #if he has not found the photo within the program
        if coords == None:
            print ("Geen login gevonden")
        #if the picture is found
        if coords != None:
            print ("Login gevonden")
            pyautogui.rightClick(coords)
        
openprogram()
inloggen()
```

Comment: Who is this "he"?

Comment: the last if statement @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: did you run script in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages? Maybe it will show you something useful.